# Tabularx Column Settings Take Up Space and Text Align Left

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, tabularx

The table below creates a 3 column table, when I use the `{l | X | X}` column settings it creates the last 2 columns of equal width which Is what I want but I also want the text within to align left.

Can this be done in the column settings?

```
\begin{table}[!htb]
\caption{Caption.....}
\label{tab:____}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{l | X | X}
\toprule
Col1 & Col2 & Col3\\
\midrule

eMail & \tabitem aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    \tabitem bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
    \tabitem cccccccccccccccccccccccc 
    & 
    \tabitem dddddddddddddddddddddd
    \tabitem eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee
    \tabitem ffffffffffffffffffffff
    \tabitem gggggggggggggggggggggg\\


\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't understand what must float. And what does‘float left’ mean?

Comment: @Bernard Align to the left

Comment: Could you post a hand-made sketch? it still is not very clear to me.

Comment: What is the meaning of `\tabitem`?

Comment: @Bernard I've added a picture of it

Comment: @Herbert it's a custom bullet point command: \newcommand{\tabitem}{~~\llap{\textbullet}~~} for use within the tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs,ragged2e}
\newcommand\tabitem{\textbullet~} 
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{>{\RaggedRight}p{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htb]
    \caption{Caption.....}\label{tab:____}
    \noindent
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{l | X | X}
        \toprule
        Col1 & Col2 & Col3\\
        \midrule

        eMail & \tabitem aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
        \tabitem bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
        \tabitem cccccccccccccccccccccccc 
        & 
        \tabitem dddddddddddddddddddddd
        \tabitem eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee
        \tabitem ffffffffffffffffffffff
        \tabitem gggggggggggggggggggggg\\

        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table} 

\end{document}
```

[image]